# How can I get every steps of Distributed test logs in Master machine?

Tags: selenium, jmeter

In jmeter webdriver sampler I am printing some logs. When I run as a simple test it creates logs. But if run as distributed test required logs are not generating, only the logs related to Distributed testing is generated but not what I am printing using webdriver sampler.

```
2017-11-27 12:09:31,733 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2017-11-27 12:09:31,733 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: FacebookThread 1-1
2017-11-27 12:09:56,630 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Actions:login,UserDetails
2017-11-27 12:09:56,632 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Timing:11687,203
2017-11-27 12:10:02,312 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: FacebookThread 1-1
2017-11-27 12:10:02,313 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: FacebookThread 1-1
2017-11-27 12:10:03,261 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2017-11-27 12:10:03,261 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

But if run it the same test in distributed mode the logs are

```
2017-11-27 12:12:14,490 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: sent test to 192.168.0.5 basedir='.'
2017-11-27 12:12:14,490 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: Sending properties {}
2017-11-27 12:12:14,490 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: sent run command to 192.168.0.5
2017-11-27 12:12:14,490 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Remote engines have been started
2017-11-27 12:12:14,490 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, 192.168.0.5)
2017-11-27 12:12:42,113 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, 192.168.0.5)
```

I need to have every step of logs in distributed testing also. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of printing values into *jmeter.log* file I would recommend saving them into JMeter Variables like

- In the WebDriver Sampler:

  ```
  var vars = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables()
  vars.put('Actions', 'login,UserDetails') // or whatever relevant action name
  vars.put('Timing', '11687,203')
  ```
- In the *user.properties*:

  ```
  sample_variables=Actions,Timing
  ```

Once you run your test you will see 2 extra columns in the .jtl result file having values for `Actions` and `Timing` JMeter Variables for each and every sampler.

More information:

- [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered)

Answer (score 0):

The logs related to distributed testing in jmeter will be 2 types. one is jmeter.log which will be created in the single system where we are runnnig the test. but one more log jmeter-server.log will be created in jmeter server systems. you go to bin folder of each system and find jmeter-server.log

If test runs for long time or it is long test your logs will be deleted due to log file configuration. so better idea is have a code in where in it prints the output to a external file which is a better option to track the data.

Thank you.